# ViewPagerIndicator not changing colours

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have integrated [CirclePageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java) to viewpager.I am trying to change the fill colour and page colour but it shows default colour only.Below is the code i am trying.

layout

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
     android:id="@+id/circles"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/header"
     android:layout_above="@+id/popup_achievement" />
```

Class

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
circlePageIndicator.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
circlePageIndicator.setRadius(15);
circlePageIndicator.setPageColor(R.color.gray);
circlePageIndicator.setFillColor(R.color.das_color);
circlePageIndicator.setStrokeColor(R.color.dffe_color);
circlePageIndicator.setSnap(true);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to open the CirclePageIndicator class. Then you will find all those like below:

```
    //Load defaults from resources
    final Resources res = getResources();
    final int defaultPageColor = res.getColor(com.viewpagerindicator.R.color.default_circle_indicator_page_color);
    final int defaultFillColor = res.getColor(com.viewpagerindicator.R.color.default_circle_indicator_fill_color);
    final int defaultOrientation = res.getInteger(com.viewpagerindicator.R.integer.default_circle_indicator_orientation);
    final int defaultStrokeColor = res.getColor(com.viewpagerindicator.R.color.default_circle_indicator_stroke_color);
    final float defaultStrokeWidth = res.getDimension(com.viewpagerindicator.R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_stroke_width);
    final float defaultRadius = res.getDimension(com.viewpagerindicator.R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_radius);
    final boolean defaultCentered = res.getBoolean(com.viewpagerindicator.R.bool.default_circle_indicator_centered);
    final boolean defaultSnap = res.getBoolean(com.viewpagerindicator.R.bool.default_circle_indicator_snap);
```

from here change whatever you need change. thanks